# Sum elements in a list by index within a loop

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a function that returns a oneliner pd.DataFrame. I have wrapped that function in a loop and want to aggregate the results based on an index.

```
def func(input):
     some calculation
     return oneliner
```

`oneliner` looks like this

```
date         return   return_lev
20100101      0.05      0.0725
```

My loop produces now several of these oneliners and I would like to aggregate all the oneliners if they have the same date otherwise just append the onliner:

```
df = []
for x in range(0, 10)
    res = func(x)
    df.append(res).groupby(by = 'date').sum()
```

However, this tells me:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

Even if I take out `groupby`, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

Any idea, how I could solve this?

edit: here we go, I have a function that produces random numbers as a oneliner, similar to my results.

```
df_date = pd.DataFrame(['20100101', '20100102', 
                    '20100103', '20100104', '20100105'], columns = ['date'])

from random import randint

def test_func(i):
    a = randint(0, 9) + i
    b = randint(0, 9) / 10 + i
    c = randint(0, 9) + i
    d = randint(0, 9) / 10 + i
    datetime = df_date.sample(1)

    a_s = pd.Series(a, dtype = int)
    b_s = pd.Series(b, dtype = float)
    c_s = pd.Series(c, dtype = int)
    d_s = pd.Series(d, dtype = float)

    overview = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([a_s, b_s, c_s, d_s]).reshape(1, 4), 
                            columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], index = datetime)

    return overview
```

now with my previous attempt:

```
dfs_test = []

for x in range(5):
    test_results = test_func(x)
    dfs_test.append(test_results).groupby(by = 'datetime').sum()
```

this gives me as above

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

now with the other version, where I produce an array / list:

```
from random import randint

def test_func_2(i):
    a = randint(0, 9) + i
    b = randint(0, 9) / 10 + i
    c = randint(0, 9) + i
    d = randint(0, 9) / 10 + i
    datetime = df_date.sample(1)

    a_s = pd.Series(a, dtype = int)
    b_s = pd.Series(b, dtype = float)
    c_s = pd.Series(c, dtype = int)
    d_s = pd.Series(d, dtype = float)

    overview = [datetime, a_s, b_s, c_s, d_s]

    return overview
```

and now with the list version:

```
dfs_test_2 = pd.DataFrame([test_func_2(z) for z in range(5)],
                  columns=['datetime', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

dfs_test_2 = dfs_test_2.groupby('datetime').sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: What you have is not a list of lists, it is a list of dataframes. You need to modify your function so that it returns a list. Since you haven't shared this code for `func`, we can't help resolve the issue.

Comment: @jpp: Could you advise how to best share the code? it's a very long code; I am currently trying to write an example function that produces similar output, such that we can try it in a loop, please bear with me

Comment: That's a difficult one. You will have to do some work to provide a *[mcve]*. It might take some time, but it's time well spent.

Comment: @jpp: I created two versions: one original (inefficient pd.DataFrame first and then list) and the second one (attempt to change to list / array and then make pd.DataFrame). When I run these I get the same errors as running the original code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea of returning a list of dataframes and then appending them or adding a result via a loop is inefficient.

Instead, I advise you output a list of lists and then build your dataframe in one step.

```
def func(var):
    """Return list of [date, return, return_lev]"""
    # some calculation
    return [a, b, c]

# build dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([func(x) for x in range(10)],
                  columns=['date', 'return', 'return_lev'])

# perform groupby
df = df.groupby('date').sum().reset_index()
```

---

**Update**: Your function to return a list of scalars actually returns a list of `pd.Series` objects.

Try something like the below:

```
def test_func_2(i):
    a = randint(0, 9) + i
    b = randint(0, 9) / 10 + i
    c = randint(0, 9) + i
    d = randint(0, 9) / 10 + i
    datetime = df_date.sample(1).values[0][0]

    overview = [datetime, a, b, c, d]

    return overview
```

Comment: thank you for the tipp with building the data frame afterwards. The dataframe build there is a concatenation of (1x1) pd.Series. I have tried to create a list or an array similar in you solution. But when running the code I get the following error: `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate` and `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`, which I assume comes from my list returned by the function. I asssume it's because of the pd.Series?

Comment: In that case, you need to provide some data so we can replicate your error. For example, **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49882714/edit)** your question with a list of lists (e.g. 10 rows), and we can then see where the problem lies.

Comment: thank you, in fact I could take all the variables and make them a scalar like you did with datetime, pd.Series.values. Will revert asap

Comment: it works as you suggested! Now the loop has another problem for a function that uses the subset data frames to create a list of tuples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49909524/python-keyerror-0-function-that-creates-a-list-from-subsets-of-data-frame-ac